# How do I extract a column from a pandas dataframe in order to use it indepedently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv pandas pivot table that I want to normalize. Every column has to be divided by the values in the 9:30 column so that the data scales up to "1".
[image: csv]

Here is what I tried:

```py
columns = table.columns
    for col in table[columns]:
        table[col] = table[col]/table[columns[0]]
```

"table" is the pivot table dataframe.
I put the column names into "columns", because they are datetime format.

The issue is that since the first column is divided, all the values turn to 1 (which is what I want), but then all the other columns stay the same, for what I can only assume is because the rest of the columns are being divided by "1", and not the original values.

So what I'm thinking of is to isolate the 9:30 column and create a separate copy of it, in order to use it for the division and so it doesn't change the original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data with `.copy()`:

```
divisor = table.iloc[:,0].copy()

for col in columns:
        table[col] /= divisor
```

However, in your case, you can just do `div`:

```
table = table.div(table.iloc[:,0],axis=0)
```

Comment: Wow, that's surprisngly simple. Could you explain what it does explicitly? I mean I know "what" it does because it achieves my desired outcome, but not the code itself. I had intially messed around with .div but had no idea how to work it

Comment: As the name suggested, `copy` copies the data to a new memory so you won't alter it within the `for` loop. The 2nd code is just straightforward dividing `table` by the series column-wise (default is row-wise or `axis=1`) all at once, so you don't need to copy. The examples from the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) are pretty good.